# Meteor bcrypt and errors for xcodebuild

Tags: node.js, meteor

Meteor: 1.4.1.1
Terminal reporting node version 5.5.0

Starting Meteor project from the Mac machine terminal I get:

```
=> Started MongoDB.                           
Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
In order to use the native implementation instead, run

  meteor npm install --save bcrypt
```

So I run the suggested command and I get:

```
todo$meteor npm install --save bcrypt

> bcrypt@0.8.7 install /Users/path-to-app-folder/todo/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

2016-09-13 02:37:10.106 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] DVTPlugInManager: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for KSImageNamed.ideplugin (com.ksuther.KSImageNamed) not present
2016-09-13 02:37:11.039 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeColors.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-09-13 02:37:11.055 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeBoost.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-09-13 02:37:11.079 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Swimat.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-09-13 02:37:11.096 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/SCXcodeSwitchExpander.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-09-13 02:37:11.097 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-09-13 02:37:11.125 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/BBUDebuggerTuckAway.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-09-13 02:37:11.127 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Backlight.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-09-13 02:37:11.138 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/AutoHighlightSymbol.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-09-13 02:37:11.164 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Auto-Importer.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-09-13 02:37:11.181 xcodebuild[13920:1609638] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bcrypt_lib.node
todo@ /Users/path-to-app-folder/todo
└─┬ bcrypt@0.8.7 
  ├── bindings@1.2.1 
  └── nan@2.3.5 

todo$
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Anyone have an updated solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor accounts-password package uses bcrypt. Your current version may be incompatible. Can you check the version of accounts-password in the versions file? At best it should be 1.3.0

To fix this, try and run these commands one by one:

```
meteor npm install -g node-gyp
meteor npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
meteor npm install -g node-pre-gyp
meteor npm install -g chokidar
meteor npm install --save bcrypt
```

Comment: The accepted answer no longer works, the second line gives many Errors.